How can I transfer daily Facebook ads data using AWS AppFlow?
I am using the Facebook Ads connector in AWS AppFlow to transfer Facebook Ads data. While I can successfully transfer all data objects, the data for ads is being accumulated over the entire lifetime of the ads rather than on a daily basis.
For instance, when generating reports using Facebook's Graph API, I retrieve daily data as follows:
https://graph.facebook.com/{ad_id}/insights?fields={field_names}&time_range={'since':'2021-08-19','until':'2021-08-20'}
https://graph.facebook.com/{ad_id}/insights?fields={field_names}&time_range={'since':'2021-08-20','until':'2021-08-21'}
https://graph.facebook.com/{ad_id}/insights?fields={field_names}&time_range={'since':'2021-08-21','until':'2021-08-22'}

I would like to achieve the same daily data transfer using AWS AppFlow for the entire duration the ad has been running. How can I configure AWS AppFlow to transfer the ads data on a daily basis instead of the accumulated data over the ad's lifetime? Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.
I have got the following data transferred for the lifetime of ad run between 2021-08-17 and 2024-06-05
{"account_currency":"USD","account_id":"","account_name":"","actions":[{"action_type":"onsite_conversion.post_save","value":"7"},{"action_type":"comment","value":"10"},{"action_type":"link_click","value":"433"},{"action_type":"post","value":"39"},{"action_type":"like","value":"3969"},{"action_type":"post_reaction","value":"2847"},{"action_type":"page_engagement","value":"7305"},{"action_type":"post_engagement","value":"3336"}],"ad_id":"","ad_name":"","adset_id":"","adset_name":"","buying_type":"AUCTION","campaign_id":"","campaign_name":"","clicks":"8000", "date_start":"2021-08-17","date_stop":"2024-06-05"

What I need is a daily level data transfer for all the days between 2021-08-17 and 2024-06-05 i.e, for all the days the ad has run.
